# How to change from PhD thesis to PhD Thesis in references?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @phdthesis{author_book,
  title = {Book's title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2005},
 }
 
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography as desired.
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{author_book}
 
\printbibliography
 
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the picture below, this yields "PhD thesis", where the word *thesis* is not capitalised. I'd like to get the word *thesis* capitalised (i.e., *Thesis*). How can I do that?

Thank you all!

[image]

Comment: `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{phdthesis = {PhD Thesis}}` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simplistic way is to announce that you want the word capitalized:

```
 @phdthesis{author_book,
  title = {Book's title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2005},
  type = {PhD Thesis},
 }
```

For a single entry it's the simplest way. Otherwise

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @phdthesis{author_book,
  title = {Book's title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2005},
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  isbn=false,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=3,
  hyperref=true,
]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography as desired.

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  phdthesis = {PhD\addabbrvspace Thesis}
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{author_book}
 
\printbibliography
 
\end{document}
```